# How many product features to include on a homepage

Tags: homepage, features, product

I'm designing a brand website for a product that has around 12 features. I will create a page to disclose all feature details, but I wanna showcase the most important features on the homepage. How many features roughly should I include on the homepage?

Comment: Just 12? [Mac OS Big Sur](https://www.apple.com/macos/big-sur/) shows and describe nearly 30 features at the same page.

Comment: @Danielillo True, but it's not their homepage. I wanna make the homepage concise and light. If visitors wanna see all features, they can always go to the page dedicated to that.

Comment: I don't think there is a minimum number, just as I don't think 12 is such a big number. Four columns by three rows is nothing

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you need to ask marketing or sales department - which features are hot sellers. Or what features should be offered first due to this webpage or even whole website audience? Or what features better distinguish your product from competitors?

Another thing if your internal customers ask you to show 12 features, so the question is how to present them in the best way.

Number of features depends on goods itself. Imagine it is motherboard. Do you want to provide full specification or just supported CPU and form factor?

Comment: Agreed -- this isn't something the designer can be expected to know.